# Convert the results of a list into json and save into a json file

Tags: r

Having this line it is possible to save the results into a list:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httpuv)
library(httr)

i<-1
results <- list()
for (a in 1:2) {
   getURL = paste0("https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=sentiment+committer-date:2000-01-01..2023-01-20&sort=committer-date&order=asc&per_page=100&page=",a)
    req <- GET(getURL)
    data <- content(req)
    results[[i]] <- data
    Sys.sleep(5)
    i <- i + 1
    print(i)
}

for (i in 1:length(results)){
    results[[i]]$total_count <- NULL
    results[[i]]$incomplete_results <- NULL
}
```

How is it possible to convert the results list into json and save it into json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `jsonlite::toJSON()`:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(httpuv)
library(httr)

i<-1
results <- list()
for (a in 1:2) {
  getURL = paste0("https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=sentiment+committer-date:2000-01-01..2023-01-20&sort=committer-date&order=asc&per_page=100&page=",a)
  req <- GET(getURL)
  data <- content(req)
  results[[i]] <- data
  i <- i + 1
  print(i)
}
#> [1] 2
#> [1] 3

for (i in 1:length(results)){
  results[[i]]$total_count <- NULL
  results[[i]]$incomplete_results <- NULL
}

results_json <- toJSON(results, pretty = TRUE)
out <- tempfile(fileext = ".json")
cat(results_json, file = out)
```

First lines of the saved file:

```r
head(readLines(out))
#> [1] "["                                                                                                                                  
#> [2] "  {"                                                                                                                                
#> [3] "    \"items\": ["                                                                                                                   
#> [4] "      {"                                                                                                                            
#> [5] "        \"url\": [\"https://api.github.com/repos/dspinellis/linux-history-repo/commits/e8f884162cbba5c890bec7a002a9e7588e269db4\"],"
#> [6] "        \"sha\": [\"e8f884162cbba5c890bec7a002a9e7588e269db4\"],"
```